# Flutter I want to get navigator from my Gridview to different pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-engine

I want to navigate to a different page with every single page in the photo  or it's better to use ListView.

[image]

Comment: Post your data_item.dart content

Answer (score -1):

hey buddy hope my answer can solve your issue

you can use GridView.builder and in builder property

code like....

builder: (BuildContext context, Int index){
return GestureDetector(onTap:(){
...you can use navigator...
})
})

AND' if you want to on every page navigate the diffrent screen the use switch case in order to maintain it's index
But this is more Lengthy method when there are more count is available.